# Nan encountered when using numba

Tags: numpy, numba

I am using Numba to speed up a function and I bumped into the following problem.
When using the decorator @njit (or @jit) the behaviour of some numpy function is changed.
For example if I use the following function to calculate tanh

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np    
@njit
    def check_tanh(z):
        return np.tanh(z)
```

and I run it for real values of z I get the same as np.tanh(z) as it should be.
If I move instead parallel to the real axis but with an imaginary part, for example z = x+ 1.j, and increase x, the numpy tanh will converge to 1.+0.j, while check_tanh(z) will return a nan (on my computer this is happening when x>360).

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on and how can be fixed?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using tanh from cmath fixes the issue.
Seems that is still a problem in Numba
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2919